# private static field Java

Tags: java, static, field, private, final

I was asked the following question:

Assuming all instance fields and all instance methods of class A in Java are private, which of the following are correct:

1. A is immutable
2. A is not for sure immutable because it could be that it extends a not-immutable class
3. A is not for sure immutable because you might be able to change its fields from static methods

I thought the correct answer was 1 but turns out 2 and 3 are both correct and 1 is not.

How come if everything is private you can still modify the fields?

Why if it extends a not immutable class, but still have everything private, it might be now immutable?

What does it mean to change its fields from static methods?

Comment: An immutable object is an object whose internal state remains constant after it has been entirely created. We also should have `final` keyword. For more details please read here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-immutable-object

Comment: 2. If it extends a mutable class then it has fields other than the private ones that A declares. 3. Static methods in A have full access to private fields in A so they might mutate it.

Comment: Point 2: if you have `public class A extends B`, even though all fields and methods of `A` are private, you don't know what fields are declared for `B`. It may be that `B` has non private fields / public setters. Those fields will belong to `A` too (since `A extends B`), and they may be modified from outside the class so making `A`'s state mutable.

Comment: Point 3: If inside `A` there is a `public static` method, then this method has access to private fields of `A`. If someone calls the static method from outside, this method may mute the state of private fields of `A`.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ I'm actually currently trying to access a private field from a static method in the same class, and I get the message "this cannot be referenced from a static contest". How would you be able to access it?

Comment: @ucei a `static` field or method means that it is not linked to a specific instance of the class, but it's always the same ("static") to the class itself. You need to have an instance of `A` inside the static method, if you try `A a = new A();` and then try to access a private field of `a` (let's say `a.x`), you will be able to do it even if `x` is `private` to `A`.

Answer (score 1):

A could extend a class with fields that are public, in which case, those fields can be modified despite `A` itself not defining any mutable fields, as it will inherit fields and instance methods from its parent class.

Consider the following code:

```
class Child extends Parent {
    private String name;
}
class Parent {
    public int id;
}
class TestChild {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Child child = new Child();
        //String s = child.name;<--The field Child.name is not visible
        System.out.println("Previous id: " + child.id);
        child.id = 100;//<--We can modify this because it is defined as public in Parent
        System.out.println("Updated id: " + child.id);
    }
}
```

The [output](https://ideone.com/22t39V) will be:

```
Previous id: 0
Updated id: 100
```

For the next case, it seems that the question meant methods as in instance methods, not specifying whether or not there are static methods. Static methods that are public can be called anywhere and create side effects by modifying static fields and can also access private instance fields on instances of `A`, which makes `A` not immutable.

Answer (score 1):

Point 2:

```
class B {
    public int bValue;
}

class A extends B {
    private int aValue;
}
```

An instance of A is not immutable because it has inherited a `bValue` field that can be changed.

---

Point 3:

```
class A {
    private int x;

    public static void mutate(A a) {
        a.x += 1;
    }
}
```

Instances of A can be mutated by calling the static method `A.mutate`, which has full access to A's private fields. The stipulation as it now reads, "all instance methods of class A in Java are private", does not apply to static methods.

Comment: For point 3: `Assume all fields and all methods of class A in Java are private`, shouldn't `mutate` be private?

Comment: For point 3 in the question to be true, as the OP says it is, that would have to not apply to static methods.

Comment: Yeah, seems op missed something in the question.

Comment: The original question said, "all instance fields and instance methods are private". Does this help the question? Do static methods/fields not count as instances? (I edited the question)

Comment: Yes, that is an important distinction. Static methods are not instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

All the previous answers were right. On the question regarding

> 3. A is not for sure immutable because you might be able to change its fields from static methods

can be achieved like

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A(10);
    System.out.println(a);
    A.mutateObj(20);
    System.out.println(a);
 }
}

class A {
 private static A a;
 private int x;

 A(int x) {
    this.a = this;
    this.x = x;
 }

 public static void mutateObj(int b) {
    a.x = b;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() {
    return "A{" +
            "x=" + x +
            '}';
 }
}
```

Result =>

```
A{x=10}
A{x=20}
```